# SurfaceView Sometime show blackScreen

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

On my application, I have to record video from camera.
It works fine, but some time the surface view it's black, and on the output i've only black (the sound work)
How to check if the camera not work fine, and reCreate the surface?